# Bot scheduled messages using Cron have multiple-minute delay

Tags: node.js, cron, discord.js

I've been learning how to make Discord bots recently and have been experimenting with scheduled messages. Currently, I have 8 or so messages scheduled to send throughout the week. Some send at a certain time every single day, while some send at a specific time only on the weekends, etc.

Every few weeks or so, however, the messages start sending one minute later than they're supposed to. It started with just sending one minute late, so I adjusted the time in the job to one minute later, but the delay just keeps getting worse. Now the messages are sending 7 minutes later than they're supposed to according to the time I originally set in the job.

I'm very much an amateur, and I'm not sure what might be causing this.

The only thing I have been able to come up with to remedy the problem is adjusting the time in the job, but that's definitely not an ideal solution. It works for a little while, but then the message just delays even more.

The issue still persists even after I've reset the bot, refreshed the js files, etc. as I've been working on other bot functions.

Is there a way to reset those Cron tasks specifically, so they're running on time again. Is the reason just because I have other stuff going on in the command file where those jobs are started? If so, how could I remedy that besides moving it to a separate file?

Comment: We need your code to help you

Comment: Have you made sure your system time is correct?